# How to @synthesize a C-Style array of pointers?

Tags: c, objective-c, arrays, pointers, properties

I have a property defined in a class like so:

```
@interface myClass

UIImageView *drawImage[4];
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView **drawImage;
...
@synthesize drawImage; // This fails to compile
```

I have found similar questions on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but none that really address this issue. What is the most Objective-C kosher way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't; you have to change that `retain` to `assign` and handle memory management yourself; as you can't send `-[retain]` to an `UIImageView **` (as it isn't an object.)

That is to say; you can't actually use `@synthesize` as that would lead to epic memory leaks with `assign` and doesn't work with `retain` or `copy`; what you need to do is to implement `-drawImage` and `-setDrawImage:` and write some actually accessor code.

But don't do that. Use an `NSArray`.

Comment: I'll use an NSArray, it'll make things easier down the road. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: There are valid times when you'll need to use C-style array and that is when performance is critical. NSArray is 6-7 times slower than C-style array: http://memo.tv/nsarray_vs_c_array_performance_comparison_part_ii_makeobjectsperformselector

Comment: @pixelfreak: First of all; NSArray is slower than C-style arrays *when performing certain operations*; which is an important distinction. Second, if performance is critical, you'd be probably be using OpenGL for drawing.

Answer (score 1):

The most "kosher" way would be to create an [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) of `UIImageView` objects, instead of a C-style array.

Comment: Good point, doesn't address the question tho', occasionally you need c arrays (usually not for image views, tho').

Answer (score 1):

A problem you'll encounter is that functions can't return C-style arrays in C or Objective-C, and another problem you might face is that you can't assign a pointer type to an array type (which is what your synthesised setter may be trying to do). There are at least two solutions:

1. Use an NSArray rather than a C-style array. This is the cleanest route, especially since you only have to manage the memory of one object rather than four.
2. Wrap the C-style array into a `struct`. You can't return C-style arrays straight from functions but you can return a `struct` that has an array member (be aware that there is no `retain`/`release` going on).

   ```
   typedef struct {
       UIImage *image[4];
   } ImageCollection;
   ...
   @property (nonatomic, assign) ImageCollection drawImage;
   ...
   @synthesize drawImage;
   ```